# Deleting items from a listview troubles

Tags: java, android, listview

So i'm learning android development and i started my first project a few weeks ago. Since then i've hit a few roadblocks but i've gotten past them. This one is different.

I'm trying to make it so when the user touches and holds on an item in a listview a dialogue boc pops up asking if they are sure and on Yes click it will delete the item. Simple enough right?

well here's my code:

```
//passwordList is a Set<String> and so is passList
final Set<String> passwordList = mPrefs.getStringSet("pass", new HashSet<String>());
if (passwordList != null) {
        passList = passwordList;
        listFinal = passList.toArray(new String[passList.size()]);
        list2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listFinal);
        passwordListView.setAdapter(list2);
        //onClickListener for the main list
        passwordListView.setLongClickable(true);
        passwordListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View strings, final int i, long l) {


                AlertDialog.Builder deleteConf = new AlertDialog.Builder(main.this);
                final int positionToRemove = i;

                deleteConf.setTitle("Delete Password?");
                deleteConf.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the password '" +listFinal[i] +"'?");

                deleteConf.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                deleteConf.setPositiveButton("Yes", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int w) {
                        Log.d("dialog", "Pressed YES");
                        passwordList.remove(positionToRemove);
                        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listFinal));
                        //Is this right?
                        passList.remove(positionToRemove);
                        //Or this one?
                        list.remove(positionToRemove);
                        list2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        list2.notifyDataSetInvalidated();


                    }
                });
                deleteConf.show();
                return false;

            }
        });
    }
```

I feel like i'm not removing the item from the correct array. Since the Adapter source is set to listFinal I should remove the item from there right? but it won't let me call listFinal.remove(positionToRemove);

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong here? the dialogue box shows but when I click yes nothing happens. It knows that i pressed yes (hence the log.d pressed YES) but the item is never removed.

Comment: What does it say when you try `listFinal.remove(positionToRemove)`

Comment: cannot resolve method 'remove(int)'

Comment: try not to make the onClickListener as anonymous class, but define it in the same class at a different place. It should be easy to call the list without a problem. Or, you can set the listView as a field of your class, not just a method variable. Also I guess it is not necessary to define "int i" as final.

Comment: I suggest using more descriptive names. For example, `list2` should be `adapter` or `listAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that i noticed is you have 2 objects: list and list2 and u call
list.remove();
list2.notifyDataSetChanged();

I dont see the rest of the code but this might be the case.

Comment: well list2 is the adapter and list is an ArrayList. my naming is pretty jank/:

Comment: ur code is a bit difficult to read but i see some problems. you create too many objects and i suspect you loose the reference to your list of objects and while removing you remove actually from different objects and not from your original reference. so within ur code try to call listFinal.remove(index)

Comment: the original reference is listFinal but it won't let me remove from there. says cannot resolve method. am I doing listFinal.remove() wrong?

Comment: first of all keep one single reference for ur list (passwordList) maybe in your activity. Initiate ur array adapter with this list. and either remove from the list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or call adapter.remove()

Comment: passWordList is a set so it needs to be converted into a string since it's being stored in sharedpreferences. what kind of an adapter can i use that would allow it to remain a set?

Answer (score 0):

listFinal should have been an ArrayList and not just an array